# Does Convergence in Total variation plus existence of moments imply convergence of moments?

Tags: probability-theory

If $\{P_n\}$ is sequence of probabilities distributions converging to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ in Total variation norm.  Suppose variances of the distribution $P_n$ exist for all $n$..

> Can we say then that the sequence of these variances converges to 1 ?